# what are the steps to connect to a test net?

Tags: block-producer, testnet

I have gone through the process of building latest dawn tag and ran the verification tests; what are the next steps to follow to be able to connect to a test net my brand new shiny BP?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testnets are currently run by the community, and steps to join them very by the testnet.

A good place to start is the Community Testnet channel on Telegram:

https://t.me/CommunityTestnet

Comment: thank you. 
I will select this answer cause there on the @CommunityTestnet channel most of the other testnets mentioned in the other answers can be found.

Answer (score 1):

I like to analyze the full Jungle TestNet script. It really allows you to understand how to create a block producer node and how to connect to existent ones. Check http://dev.cryptolions.io/#home -- after you register as a BP you will receive a nice script.

Or just check my outdated one: https://gist.github.com/leordev/1e12b229c28735e9defbd6249e4108c5

Still works, just update the tag version.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after a couple attempts to connect to a testnet I found what EOS Canadada is doing and I think it rocks and is the best approach to jumpstart the mainnet.

take a look for yourself
https://youtu.be/uE5J7LCqcUc

p.s. great answers above, very hard to pick one as the answer :)