# How can I create an EOS block producer?

Tags: eosio-code

I am entering into EOS development and seek advice from experts on how to produce EOS blocks and what are the rewards? Also, will a regular development device be sufficient to build such a producer?

Comment: `cleos system regproducer`

Answer (score 1):

Jungle testnet has always been the best, and helpful to say the least. Plus it is a highly active community that tests frequently.

I do suggest though that you try to build your own private-net, you can find the details of the launching sequence in the developers portal. https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence . I guarantee you will learn A LOT from doing this.

Infrastructure wise, it depends on what you want to do but usually a simple desktop with linux setting is the easiest. You can find alternatives in AWS or any other cloud service providers

Answer (score 0):

[The Jungle Testnet](http://jungle.cryptolions.io/) is where new BPs go to for testing.  You can find their tutorial on [their GitHub](https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-Jungle-Testnet).  You can also ping the team in telegram to ask for help: https://t.me/jungletestnet

Some block producers have their own infrastructure, some are using major cloud service providers.

There is also some good information here: [what are the steps to connect to a test net?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/415/what-are-the-steps-to-connect-to-a-test-net/461#461) and on [this Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/EOSDev/comments/9cyep4/jungle_testnet_basics/).